# How to store GPS lat and long to send with text message in android?

Tags: android, gps, sms, coordinates

Developing a Hiking app that sends the persons Lat and Long coordinates simply by hitting a button within the app. When I trigger the send button, the message only sends "Send emergency services to:" nullnull" meaning it is not holding the values of the lat and long with the message. I have full gps signal and have the following permissions in the manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />  

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />  

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />  

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />  

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.TELEPHONY_MANAGER" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
```

What do i need to change in my following code to make the app successfully send the lat and long coordinates with the text message. 
Apologies for all the "Toast" messages, using them for testing purposes!

```
package com.gpscamera;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button sendButton;
ImageView iv; /* result of the data returned in the if statement is 
                INCLUDED IN THE USER INTERFACE*/

TextView textLat;
TextView textLong;
String long1;
String lat1;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textLat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLat);
    textLong = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textLong);


    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener ll = new mylocationlistener();
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);

    iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    /* Reference to out imageview view  */
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.takePhoto);
    /* Makes reference to button to start the application, button name is takePhoto */
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        /* Makes the onclick listener for the button,  */

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            /* in this onclikc, must define what happens when the button is clicked. */
            /* Specified to open the image caputre*/
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            /* Starts that activity "intent" above */


              }
    });
    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Send);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        /* Makes the onclick listener for the button,  */

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            /* Starts that activity "intent" above */
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "eeeeeeeee", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            String phoneNumber = "07835588000";
            String message = "Send Emergency Services to:";

            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            ArrayList<String> parts = smsManager.divideMessage(message); 
            smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, null, null);
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "after sms", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

              }
    });
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
/* When the button is clicked it is going to start the camera, returning a result which is an image
 *  with the request code from the intent above.  */

{
    if(requestCode ==0)
    /* If the request code is = to 0 we need to get the bitmap image which is returned as out data.  */
    {
        Bitmap theImage = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        iv.setImageBitmap(theImage);
         Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "photo saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
         Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "Getting GPS loc", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
}
class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location Location) {
        try {

        if(Location != null)
        {   
            double plong = Location.getLongitude();
            double plat = Location.getLatitude();

            textLat.setText(Double.toString(plat));
            textLong.setText(Double.toString(plong));

            textLat.append(lat1);
            textLong.append(long1);

        }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(), "loss signal", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, 
            Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

}
```

Comment: `textLat.append(lat1); textLong.append(long1);` It Doesn't look like you are instantiating `lat1` or `long1` variables. Also it doesn't look like you ever actually put the lat/long values into the String that gets sent from SMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that when you get location in `public void onLocationChanged(Location Location) {` you just simply update the TextView and you don't use these actual values inside your SMSManager. Here: `smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, parts, null, null);`
 you use parts which is holding "Send Emergency Services to:" and not location's actual values.

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating ur location details in the string that is used in sending sms.  Try some thing like the Below Pseudo code. Hope it helps!!

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationText = "Current Location ="+location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude();
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, locationText, null, null);
```